# datatable column.search() is not filtering my table using

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've created a simple search but it's not filtering, I'm using datatable plug-ins. I don't know what did I missed in my script.

```
<input type="text" id="txtserial" name="txtSerial" class="form-control" />
```

Here's my javascript:

```
var dtmyJob = $('#myJob').DataTable({
     "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
     iDisplayLength: -1,
     sScrollY: "40vh",
     bScrollInfinite: true, //this property disables pagination
     "scrollCollapse": true,
     "paging": false,
     "bInfo": false,
     "bFilter": false,
     "bSort": false
 });

 $("#txtserial").on('keyup', function () {
     dtmyJob.columns(2).search(this.value).draw();
     alert(dtmyJob);
 });
```

Comment: datatables offer an automatic search field unless you disable it. Why didn't you define your columns with the columnDefs: [] property ?

Comment: @PhilMaGeo based from this sample jsfiddle. He didn't used any optional properties. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/5Lj6peof/1/)

Comment: You are right. it means in his case that the search field is automaticaly generated, but I can't see any reason why you could not make your own. Are you using an html table or an ajax request ?

Comment: Take a look at http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features  to remove the default filtering input box and retain filtering abilities, please use sDom). it means bFilter": false, don't show the automatique input field for searching but also disable searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `bFilter: false` because you have disabled searching ability and that's why searching with `columns().search()` doesn't work.

Use [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option if you just want to hide the search box.

For example:

```
'dom': 'lrtip'
```